# Inclusão de aquivos por include

Tags: php

Comprei um curso de PHP e nele o professor fez uma função genérica para incluir os arquivos no index.php. Porém quando eu adiciono uma chamada php acima do `<!DOCTYPE html>`, Some todo o código e também não faz a chamada do include de arquivos. Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço!

**index.php**

```
  <?php 
require ('./dts/dbaSis.php');
require ('./dts/getSis.php');
require ('./dts/setSis.php');
require ('./dts/outSis.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>


    </body>
    <?php include('./js/jscSis.php'); ?>
</html>
```

**jscSis.php**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php setHome(); ?>/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php setHome(); ?>/lightbox/dist/js/lightbox.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php setHome();?>/lightbox/dist/css/lightbox.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#banners').bxSlider({
              auto: true,
              autoHover: true,
              autoControls: false,
              controls: false
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        lightbox.option({
        'resizeDuration': 200,
        'wrapAround': true
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Como está sua estrutura de pasta? Se o index.php está na raiz da pasta do teu projeto e a pasta *dts* está no mesmo local, remova o ponto antes da barra.

Comment: adicione isso no topo do arquivo `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` e veja o que retorna

Comment: Está no mesmo diretório sim. eu usei o netBeans para fazer o cominho dos aquivos pelo auto complete. Já Fiz vários  testes com o caminho, mas continua o mesmo. Acrescentei o ini_set() mas não mudou nada. Se você tiver mais alguma diga eu agradeço desde já

Comment: @carlos o NetBens nem sempre usa os caminhos certos. Experimenta retirar aquele ponto antes do caminho em todos os link e vê o que dá.

Comment: Já fiz isso, em todos os caminhos e nada. Quando eu coloco esse código aqui: 
<?php 
require ('./dts/dbaSis.php');
require ('./dts/getSis.php');
require ('./dts/setSis.php');
require ('./dts/outSis.php');
?>
Não aparece o html. Vou fazer mais alguns testes e volto aqui depois.